# query INSERT INTO not work to attachment with microsoft Access and c#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

i have a query .... In a messagebox i show the query ..

[image: query]

The Error message :

> the query INSERT INTO cannot contain a multivalued field.

Why ?!? The field modulo_pdf is (in access ) attachment... but i have try to set an string and work ..

Without modulo_pdf and values

> '\\192.168.5.7\dati\SGI\GESTIONEIT\RichiesteIT\doc id_15-03-2016
>   12-21-22.pdf'

the query work good .
Where is the problem ?! \192...... is an address of NAS

Comment: what is the structure of the table you are inserting to?

Comment: Do you have the actuall error? This would be the fastest way to find where the problem is.

Comment: And what does your code look like? If you're building the SQL query up yourself, I'd strongly recommend using parameterized SQL instead, which will handle any escaping required.

Comment: Maybe you need to escape these slashes

Comment: ok ... thanks . 
The problem is with table... In table i have set that modulo_pdf -> attachment. 
modulo_pdf is a local address to pdf file. 
In this setting, the error is : the query INSERT INTO cannot contain a multivalued field.
now i setting in table that modulo_pdf is an hypertext link... and work good. 
Thanks. 
But what is an attachment? The phisical file ? how to passing an attachment to field ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to update the incorrect information. It says that the field was of type `Hyperlink` when it really was of type `Attachment`, and that was the cause of the error.

Comment: At https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-multivalued-fields-in-queries-6f64f92d-659f-411c-9503-b6624e1e323a#bm1 it mentions you have to refer to the multivalued column usnig `modulo_pdf.[Value]` to set a single value to it.